# Auto insert div after button but in a new line

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I defined a button object and a div object ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ascalon/pzh6mcL4/18/)), and to use them I write something like

```
Usually the <button class=col>cat</button> is a domestic animal.
<div class=con>It is a small mammal.</div>
But it can also be a wild animal.
```

Using [insertAdjacentHtml()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) it is possibile to automatically add the div element

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("col")[0];
button.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div class=con>It is a small mammal.</div>");
```

but in this way the div is added just after the button

```
Usually the <button class=col>cat</button><div class=con>It is a small mammal.</div> is a domestic animal.
But it can also be a wild animal.
```

Is there a way (javascript?) to add the div in the line next to the one containing the button?

Answer (score 0):

What about using instead?

```
button.append("<div class=con>It is a small mammal.</div>");
```

Comment: Where shall I write it?